# Android: datagramsocket does not receive in background (service)

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, datagram

I am using a **DatagramSocket** to receive packets in background (using service). but it does not receive when my phone is locked while when I add a **ScheduledTask** to start the thread every 1 sec, it works well. Why it doesn't work in first case and how can I fix it whitout starting the Tread every 1 sec?

```
public class RecThread2 implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      while(running){
        try {
            int MESSAGE_LEN = 60;
            byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[MESSAGE_LEN];
            DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(recvBuffer,
                    MESSAGE_LEN);
            socket1.receive(datagram);
            String recvdString = new String(recvBuffer);
            Log.i("Recieved", recvdString);
            mess = recvdString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and I run the thread here:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "receiveTag");
    wl.acquire();

    Thread sThread2 = new Thread(new runSoc1());
    sThread2.start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

But when I use the following code to run Thread periodically it works even when the phone is locked (and I remove the `while(running)` from the Thread code):

```
        time = new Timer();
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask();
        time.schedule(st, 0, 1000);
```

and :

```
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Thread sThread2 = new Thread(new RecThread2());
        sThread2.start();
    }
}
```